# Pass Activity Context to the Application class instead of Context

Tags: java, android, android-context

How Can I Pass Activity Context to Application class i Am getting the below error when i pass getApplicationContext()

```
                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:359)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:328)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:289)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialog.setContentView(AppCompatDialog.java:83)
                                                                     at
```

Comment: Error related to `Theme` not context.

Answer (score 0):

> error is not because of context it's because you need to assign appCompact theme to your activity in manifest

something like this

```
  <activity
            android:name="com.pareekshum.sociallogin.SocialLoginActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppThemeNew" />




<style name="AppThemeNew" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/actionbarbackground</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **Activity context** instead of **Application context** for specific window related components. For example, you can't use Application context for Alert dialog because it is specific window component and it uses the theme and other properties of the activity.

**Context vs Application Context**

> They are both instances of Context, but the application instance is
>   tied to the lifecycle of the application, while the Activity instance
>   is tied to the lifecycle of an Activity. Thus, they have access to
>   different information about the application environment.
>
> If you read the docs at getApplicationContext it notes that you should
>   only use this if you need a context whose lifecycle is separate from
>   the current context. This doesn't apply in either of your examples.
>
> The Activity context presumably has some information about the current
>   activity that is necessary to complete those calls. If you show the
>   exact error message, might be able to point to what exactly it needs.
>
> But in general, use the activity context unless you have a good reason
>   not to.

So if you use any window specific content or theme related content with **Application Context** it will throw this error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

Hope it helps:)

Comment: Mark it as accepted answer if it is really helped you. It will help others@Anbu